# Wiring a RGB LED on to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: led, wiring, pi-3b+

So I got a bunch of these LEDs and I can't seem to figure out how to wire them. This is what I'm working with.

[image: Back of the LED]
[image: Front of the LED]
I tried adding the gnd and 5v but it doesnt do anything. When i connect the Din to 5v and Dout to gnd it blinks very weakly. I also cant seem to find any instructions for this specific model online. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LEDs you show are intended to form part of an addressable LED strip.  You power via 5V and ground and then send a serial signal to Din.  Normally the LEDs are connected in a chain with a LED's Dout (data out) connected to the next LED's Din (data in).

As they don't appear to have a clock line (just a data line) they are likely to be hard to drive from the Pi.

You need to identify the LED type, only then will you know how they can be programmed.